# In java for When spring version upgraded to 5.3.29 and hibernate version to 5.3.29.final

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

```
The extra log is generating as 
WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImp1:501) (1 HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollector Impl:501) [1 HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl:501) [] HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollector Imp1:501) [1 HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

J WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl:501) [] HHR000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl:501) [] Hнн000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

1 WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImp1:501) [] HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImp1:501) HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

1 WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl:501) [1 HHн000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

1 WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollector Imp1:501) [1 HHR000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollector Imp1:501) D HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

WARN

(org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl:501) [1 HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

1 WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImp1:501) [] HHн000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollector Impl:501) [1 HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadatacollectorImpl:501) [] HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator

1 WARN (org.hibernate.boot.internal. InFlightMetadataCollectorImp1:501) [] HHH000069: Duplicate generator name seqGenerator
```

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It should be due to the hibernate version upgradation.
I don't rememeber the determined version.
In order to be compliant with the JPA specifications, the names of identity generators need now be considered global, and no longer scoped to the entity in which they are declared. This means existing applications might now have a naming conflict which needs to be addressed to upgrade. Configuring two generators, even with different types but with the same name,may cause some exception in your project.
So you may have to check the object generated by @TableGenerator and @SequenceGenerator,ensure the different  generator has the different name.